# How to put button and fieldLebel horizentally

Tags: css, extjs, extjs3

[image]I am trying to put button with fieldLebel. Both are coming fine but fieldLabel appearing on top of Button. How to make it horizontal alignment.

My code :

```
var dButton = new Ext.SplitButton({
        text: "Before",
        id:"B4"
        fieldLabel: "Expiry Date",
        width : 150,
        scope: this,
        labelAlign:'left',
        disabled : false
   }
```

I am trying to achieve by style but no luck.

Comment: any screen snap for this?

Comment: I updated question. Label is on top of button. I want in left.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the labelStyle property inside your SplitButton config.